# Unable to connect hive jdbc through beeline

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hadoop2, beeline

I am new to hive and wanted to make connection, I am able to do so using Hive CLI now I want to connect hive through beeline but I am getting below error while connecting.

[image]

Tried to connect hive with transportMode as http but that is also not working.

```
jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001/default;transportMode=http
```

Please refer my `hive-site.xml` file.

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name>
    <value>binary</value>
    <description>
      Expects one of [binary, http].
      Transport mode of HiveServer2.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
    <value>NONE</value>
    <description>
      Expects one of [nosasl, none, ldap, kerberos, pam, custom].
      Client authentication types.
        NONE: no authentication check
        LDAP: LDAP/AD based authentication
        KERBEROS: Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication
        CUSTOM: Custom authentication provider
                (Use with property hive.server2.custom.authentication.class)
        PAM: Pluggable authentication module
        NOSASL:  Raw transport
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.port</name>
    <value>10001</value>
    <description>Port number of HiveServer2 Thrift interface when hive.server2.transport.mode is 'http'.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.path</name>
    <value>cliservice</value>
    <description>Path component of URL endpoint when in HTTP mode.</description>
  </property>
```

Running below command does not return any value:

```
netstat -an | grep 10000
netstat -an | grep 10001
```

Comment: Running netstat -an | grep 10000 does not return any value - Can you confirm hive service is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beeline` requires `HiveServer2` process to be running.

If this is a vanilla installation, you can start HiveServer2 as a background process using this command,

```
nohup $HIVE_HOME/bin/hiveserver2 &
```

In addition to this, you have to add the user `hiveuser` or any user used when connecting via beeline as the proxyuser to be able to access HDFS

Add these properties to `core-site.xml` of HDFS and restart the services.

```
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hiveuser.hosts</name> 
     <value>*</value> 
</property> 
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hiveuser.groups</name>
     <value>*</value>
</property>
```